# SEC_Overlay called many times with Relative Layout

Tags: android, logging, android-relativelayout, preview

After getting so much help from Stack-Overflow I'd like to share back some of my experience:
I spent hour of debugging with one special

```
09-18 08:11:37.177: DEBUG/SEC_Overlay(128): overlay_setPosition(-1) 03,680,90,120 => 503,680,90,120
09-18 08:11:37.177: INFO/SEC_Overlay(128): Nothing to do!
```

This is logged each time the GLSurfaceview is updating. But only when the GLSurfaceview is used in combination with a relative Layout and a camera preview. This is combination is essential for the AndroAngelo App. On the main screen I have the radial OnScreenMenu overlayed onto the GLSurface view and on the calibration screen I put the result of the image detection onto the preview.
It decreases the performance essentially.
What to do?
I really did not went to the ground of it. It appeared two times. The second time it just disappeared after a restart of the eclipse. The first time maybe also, but I played around with camera parameters. And then it disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

It comes back from time to time. It seems to be something in the phone. Each time it appears, i simple reboot the Android device and it is gone afterwards.